# Entrar em página usando o ID do banco em ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, url

Preciso fazer uma página que possa ser acessada no seguinte formato:

`www.exemplo.com/id/123qwe`

Esse `123qwe` é o `ID` de uma linha da base de dados, onde pegarei todos os dados pra preencher a página.

Até agora consegui fazer `www.exemplo.com/id/id.aspx?id=123qwe` usando:

```
<%=Request.QueryString["id"] %>
```

Como faço para utilizar `www.exemplo.com/id/123qwe` em vez de `www.exemplo.com/id/id.aspx?id=123qwe`?

Comment: você está usando webForms ou MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você estiver usando *ASP.NET WebForms* teria de criar um [`HttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx) ou usar o [`RouteCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#adding_routes_to_a_web_forms_application). No caso do ASP.NET MVC basta adicionar uma rota.

### ASP.NET WebForms - Forma 1 (qualquer versão)

Criando a rota:

```
public class EmployeeHandlerFactory : IHttpHandlerFactory
{
   ...

   public IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, 
     string requestType, string url, string pathTranslated)
   {
      // determine the employee's name
      string empName = 
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( 
        context.Request.PhysicalPath);

      // Add the Employee object to the Items property
      context.Items.Add("Employee Info", 
        EmployeeFactory.GetEmployeeByName(empName));

      // Get the DisplayEmployee.aspx HTTP handler
      return PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(url, 
        context.Server.MapPath("DisplayEmployee.aspx"), context);
   }
}
```

Criando a página

```
public class DisplayEmployee : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   // three Label Web controls in HTML portion of page
   protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblName;
   protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblSSN;
   protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblBio;

   private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
      // load Employee information from context
      Employee emp = (Employee) Context.Items["Employee Info"];

      if (emp != null)
      {
         // Assign the Employee properties to the Label controls
         lblName.Text = emp.Name;
         lblSSN.Text = emp.SSN;
         lblBio.Text = emp.Biography;
      }
   }
```

Atualizando o `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <!-- EmployeeHandlerFactory -->
      <add verb="*" path="*.info" 
         type="skmHttpHandlers.EmployeeHandlerFactory, 
         skmHttpHandlers" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>}
```

Efeito final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### ASP.NET WebForms - Forma 2 (Apenas ASP.NET 3.5+)

No arquivo `Global.asax` inclua:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "Category/{action}/{categoryName}",
        "~/categoriespage.aspx");
}
```

### ASP.NET MVC

Adicione a rota diretamente na classe de sua aplicação:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente resposta, @AlexandreMarcondes.

Comment: Obrigado @TiagoCésarOliveira. Quero traduzir as variáveis do código, mas estou corrido com algumas coisas aqui. Em breve devo fazer isso.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcondes, como faço para editar isso para o meu projeto? Ainda não compreendi esse Category, action, etc. No meu projeto, usando WebForms (3.5+), como ficaria? Preciso acessar exemplo.com/id/123qwe (que seria exemplo.com/id/index.php?id=123qwe) e depois pegar o id '123qwe' no código.

Tentei: routes.MapPageRoute("",
                    "id/{id}",
                    "~/index.aspx"); e não foi.

Comment: @GutoSchiavon que erro deu nesse exemplo que você tentou? Ou simplesmente não funciona sem dar erro?

Comment: Ao tentar acessar http://localhost:56619/id/123qwe, ele diz reporta "Não é possível encontrar o recurso".

Comment: Mas @GutoSchiavon, tem um registro com esse id no banco?

Comment: Sim, tem sim. O erro não de não ter registro  e sim de não encontrar a página.

Comment: Você usou qual técnica?

Comment: Consegui agora: | routes.MapPageRoute("identificao", "id/{id}", "~/id.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", "1" } }); |. Agora como faço pra recuperar esse ID no meu Select, dentro do SQL Data Source?

Comment: Edita sua pergunta coloca uma barra separando e coloca o código que você usou, por favor. Adiciona isso na pergunta que vai ajudar muito as pessoas e ajudar a entender em que ponto você está. Não esquece de falar como está fazendo a conexão com banco de dados: entity framework, ado, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc), que implementa isso automaticamente para você. A rota padrão de um projeto MVC (já criada de início) é a seguinte:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

O que significa que você teria uma URL do tipo Home/Index/123qwe funcionando por default. Aí bastaria ler esse ID no seu controler e usá-lo:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
```

Comment: Estou usando um projeto ASP.Net Webforms com DevExpress.

Essa rota eu configuro onde?

Comment: Não tem como @GutoSchiavon isso é ASP.NET MVC e não WebForms. tem que converter sua aplicação para usar isso.

Comment: @GutoSchiavon você poderia até configurar rotas no seu Web Forms, mas acredite, não vale a pena pelo esforço. Recomendo fortemente a adoção do padrão MVC, junto a outros frameworks  nativos que te ajudarão bastante em suas tarefas (especialmente o Entity Framework, de início, atrelado ao MVC).

Comment: Seu projeto ainda está no início? Se sim, vale o esforço em adaptar ao MVC!

Comment: Sim @TiagoCésarOliveira, meu projeto está no inicio. Vou tentar a adaptação para o MVC. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @GutoSchiavon disponha! Se estiver usando o Visual Studio 2012 ou 2013, já use a versão 5 do MVC...

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira ainda estou na versão 2010, visto que é a versão usada pela empresa onde estagio.

Comment: Nesse caso acho que vc tem acesso ao MVC 4 que também é uma boa

Answer (score 1):

.Net 4.0 em diante já é possível usar as rotas do MVC em projeto webforms, eu mesmo uso.
No Global.asax você deve registrar as rotas.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("SalesRoute",
      "SalesReport/{locale}/{year}",
      "~/sales.aspx");
```

E para acessar o valor na página aspx você usa o seguinte código:

```
Page.RouteData.Values["locale"]
Page.RouteData.Values["year"]
```

Comment: No caso, aplicando ao meu projeto, como ficaria? ainda não consegui entender mto bem a sintaxe das rotaas.

Comment: Adiciona o código que registra a rota para sua página aspx, lá no arquivo Global.asax, no método Start.  RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("SalesRoute" ...

Comment: @GutoSchiavon Veja aquin na minha resposta como fazer: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7087/280